# Redirect from asp to php with session variables

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, session

I have a web application based on ASP .NET and a knowledge center website based on WordPress.

Within the web application, I have an option to view knowledge center. When a user clicks this option, I would like to take them to WordPress site with their name passed in session.
I realize that .Net application and WordPress site will have 2 different sessions, I would like to pass the session variable name from ASP .Net application to WordPress(PHP). This is because I would like to customize the homepage page of knowledge center with user's name.

Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: so you need a centralized session storage, like an external database, to handle your tokens. then on both ends you can rely on this database and authenticate users with this token over multiple domains.keywords: `share session php asp, SSO`

Comment: @chorn Can I simply create a php page with session variable in the url and pass it to the second site, there I can use $GET to get the parameter in the url and use it? thoughts?

Comment: this way you only have some un-authorized, effectively random string on your asp page you can not trust. you still need a service that stores *valid* tokens for your asp page to be checked.